Unable to clone git repo
i am try to host my repo through streamlit cloud services it , it is failing to clone the repo ,
.
i got the mail form git lfs as,

Git LFS has been disabled on your personal account Mohansharma13
because you’ve exceeded your data plan by at least 150%. Please
purchase additional data packs to cover your bandwidth and storage
usage:
https://github.com/account/billing/data/upgrade
Current usage as of 25 Jun 2024 05:28PM UTC:
Bandwidth: 1.54 GB / 1 GB (154%)   Storage: 0.24 GB / 1 GB (24%)

the repo i am trying to host is https://github.com/Mohansharma13/movie-recommendation-system
as files was large i use git lfs to push them ,now i am trying to host my app but facing with problem

Please include any text based information (such as that in your screenshot) as text within the question so that it is searchable. Thank you

Git LFS doesn't affect streamlit.
as seen in screenshot you provided it's authentication error
since the repo url you provided is correct, just ensure that the credentials match your repository url.
for example, if you used https://github.com/Mohansharma13/movie-recommendation-system.git then credentials will be username & PAT, if it's git@github.com:Mohansharma13/movie-recommendation-system.git then you need to configure the SSH connection between streamlit and GitHub
